# スペースキーを押すごとに、四角形の大きさを2倍、1倍、2倍、1倍とトグします？

Tags: java, processing

```
float x = 400, y=100;
int a=20,b=10;
void setup() { size(800, 200); }
void draw() {
rect(x-10, y-5, a, b);
}
void keyPressed() {
  int k=' ';
if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
x++;
} else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
x--;
} else if (keyCode == UP){
  y--;
} else if (keyCode == DOWN){
  y++;
}
}
```

Comment: だれか教えていただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、Processingにおいて四角形の大きさをトグルさせたいということでよいでしょうか？　また、Sakuraさんはどのようにやろうとしてみて行き詰まりましたか？　動かなくて良いので、どういうことを試してみたか質問文に書いてみて頂けませんでしょうか。質問文下の「編集」から自由に編集できますので、お願いいたします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実際はカーソルキーを用いて、上下左右ができたんですが、次はスペースキーを押すごとに、四角形の大きさを2倍、1倍、2倍、1倍とトグさせたいですが、できなかったので、こちらに質問しました。

Comment: コメントではなく、質問文に追記してみてください。今のままだとご質問の内容がよく分かりません。特に、トグルさせるためにどんなコードを書いてみたのかがあれば書いてみてください。

Comment: @Sakura  「トグする≒トグる」ではなく「トグル = toggle」です、念のため。

Comment: [本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54310184/8248751)で解決済のようですが、そちらの回答はトグルしていないような…。

Answer (score 1):

スペースキーを押すたびに`拡大中`かどうかを示す変数を書き換えることで、サイズをトグルして管理できます。
下記のサンプルコードではスペースを押すたびに`isExtended`変数を書き換えて、[三項演算子](https://processing.org/reference/conditional.html)で`a`と`b`の値を制御しています。

```
float x = 400, y = 100;
int a = 20, b = 10;
boolean isExtended = false;
void setup() { size(800, 200); }
void draw() {
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, 800, 200);
  rect(x - a / 2, y - b / 2, a, b);
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    x++;
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    x--;
  } else if (keyCode == UP){
    y--;
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN){
    y++;
  } else if (keyCode == ' ') {
    isExtended = !isExtended;
    a = isExtended ? 40 : 20;
    b = isExtended ? 20 : 10;
  }
}
```